# ¿Cómo traducirían el anglicismo "feature vector"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, matemáticas

¿Saben como expresar en castellano el anglicismo "**feature vector**"?

Quiero referirme al vector que almacena características (en el contexto de Inteligencia Artificial).

Particularmente encuentro el problema de que algunos lo llaman "**vector característico**" y otros lo llaman "**vector de características**". ¿Existe una diferencia semántica entre ambas expresiones o podría usarlas indistintamente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No soy ningún experto en AI, pero tras darle una ojeada al [artículo correspondiente en Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_vector):

> In pattern recognition and machine learning, a feature vector is an n-dimensional vector of numerical features that represent some object.

Veo que es un vector de valores numéricos, cada uno de los cuales se identifica con una característica. Por tanto se podría llamar "vector de características".
Sin embargo, todas esas características juntas representan un objeto; por tanto ese vector con esos valores particulares podría llamarse el "vector característico" de ese objeto.

Desde mi punto de vista, "**vector de características**" parece ligeramente más apta para todos los contextos, pero por lo demás encuentro ambas expresiones intercambiables entre sí.

Comment: I think _vector de caracteristicas_ is clearly preferable (+1) as it is a vector of features which is the term ML people use for what as a statistician I would call a vector of predictors. For me _vector caracteristico_ sounds too similar to https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_caracter%C3%ADstica for comfort.

Comment: Gracias @walen me inclinaré por vector de características también

Comment: and thank you @mdewey nice to have the statistician point of view

Comment: Tampoco soy experto en AI, pero sí trabajo con JavaScript a diario y me parece que se está hablando de un "Array" o arreglo o vector n-dimensional. Si dicho vector no contiene valores númericos, pero sí contiene "strings" o cadenas de texto que representan características, entonces sí es gramaticalmente correcto hablar de un **Vector de Características** ya que contiene las características o propiedades de un objeto. Esto se ve mucho en la programación orientada a objetos (POO o OOP por sus siglas en Inglés).

Answer (score 5):

Para complementar la [excelente respuesta de walen](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21385/5481) (y la sugerencia de mdewey) yo añadiría que ["vector característico"](http://fcm.ens.uabc.mx/~matematicas/algebralineal/VI%20Valores%20y%20Vectores%20Propios/01%20propios.htm) es un término que ya se usa en el álgebra lineal (como sinónimo de *[eigenvector](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_propio_y_valor_propio)*).

Con lo cual la traducción de vuelta al inglés de "vector característico" sería ["characteristic vector"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) y estaríamos sobrecargando el término en español al usarlo tanto para `characteristic vector` como para `feature vector`.

Por eso creo que la mejor traducción es la de "**vector de características**".

Comment: De verdad que solo conocía la expresión **eigenvector** o **vector propio** para el concepto en álgebra lineal, esto aclara cualquier duda